# Passing dynamic arguments to an exe file with PHP

Tags: php, exe, executable

I have users who will download an exe file from my website. I would like to pass dynamic command line arguments to the exe file to be able to track installs for my software.

For example, a user will visit this site: http://blabla.com/download.php?id=123abc

I would like this page to give the user an executable file that will run like this:

install.exe /id 123abc

I have no idea how to do this. Some guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think it's possible to make an executable file run with parameters by default without some kind of script. Bu Why don't you make your application report the installation to you ? you could just access a webservice, or simply have a prepared web page with a counter,

Comment: perhaps you can give them an executable and a batch file to run it with parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try patching some hardcoded string in the exe file with the users ID.

Or create an install-package that creates a shortcut to your program along with some command line stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to simply require the software's end user to have to enter a unique code generated by the site (along with some other identifying information) in order to use the software.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the compiler with the user ID hardcoded while the user requests the exe.

Comment: If I'm expecting a large volume of downloads - would this be too stressful on the server?

Comment: probably yes, depends how long does the application compile ;)